# C++ modifying a class passed by reference does not change the original object

Tags: c++, oop, pass-by-reference

I have a class A that contains a couple of instance variables and a class B that takes a reference to that class and changes the instance variables. After class B changes those variables, you would think that those would get changed in the original instance of the class, but in this case they do not. Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

```
class Foo {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Foo() {

    }
    Foo(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};

class Bar {
public:
    Foo foo;
    Bar() {

    }
    Bar(Foo& foo) {
        this->foo = foo;   
    }
    void Swap() {
        int tmp = foo.x;
        foo.x = foo.y;
        foo.y = tmp;
    }
};
int main()
{
  Foo foo(4, 8);
  Bar bar(foo);

  std::cout << "this is x: " << foo.x << std::endl; //prints 4
  std::cout << "this is y: " << foo.y << std::endl; //prints 8

  bar.Swap();
  std::cout << "this is x: " << foo.x << std::endl; //prints 4, but should print 8
  std::cout << "this is y: " << foo.y << std::endl; //prints 8, but should print 4
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `Bar` holds a copy of the source `Foo`, not a reference to the source `Foo`. The `Foo` was passed into the function by reference, but was then copied.

Comment: user4581301 is right, you should use `foo->bar.Swap();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `B`'s constructor does take `foo` (the parameter) by reference, but immediately copies it into a separate instance of `A` (in particular, into the `foo` member); `Swap` then works on the `foo` member, which, as said above, is just a copy of the original object.

To make your code behave as you expect you have to make even the member `foo` a reference (or a pointer):

```
class Bar {
public:
    Foo &foo;
    Bar() {

    }
    Bar(Foo& foo) : foo(foo) {
    }
```

(notice that I had to use [the member initialization list syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) because references [cannot be default-initialized and then reseated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992121/must-a-reference-type-be-initialized-in-constructor-initialization-list))

Comment: Thanks for the help, going from c# to c++ has been a little tricky with the way c++ handles pointers amd references.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
    Foo foo;
    Bar(Foo& foo) {
        this->foo = foo;   
    }
```

Even though you take the `foo` argument by reference, you assign it to a non-reference value, which results in a copy and accounts for the problem you posed. The first step to the solution is declaring your instance field by reference as well.

```
    Foo& foo;
```

But this results in an error when you try to assign to it. To this end, we want to use a special constructor initialization syntax. It does basically the same thing as assignment but performs construction rather than normal assignment. So write your constructor as follows.

```
    Bar(Foo& foo) : foo(foo) {}
```

You'll also have to remove the default constructor `Bar()` completely, as most C++ compilers will reject code that could result in an uninitialized reference.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a reference to foo to the constructor of bar, but then assign (copy) the foo that you've passed by reference to bar.foo.

You want to declare it as a reference to (or pointer to) a Foo object, not a separate Foo object.